# Use IN clause in python django and cursor execute

Tags: python, django, in-clause

I have a list named "`critical_severity_list`" as below:`[30, 40]`

I want to execute a select with IN clause as below:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()

que = 'select * from tm_txn_age_severity_config where txn_state_id = %s and txn_type_id = %s and txn_age_severity_id in ( %s)'

in_ids = ', '.join(map(lambda x: '%s', critical_severity_list))

que = que % ('%s', in_ids)

bind_var_list = [] 

bind_var_list.append(rec[1])

bind_var_list.append(rec[2])

bind_var_list.extend(critical_severity_list)

cursor.execute(que, bind_var_list)

result = cursor.fetchall()
```

I am getting this error:
not enough arguments for format string

Can someone help me with the solution....??

Comment: your code is expecting `que % ('%s','%s','%s')` and I am not sure what this will do.

Comment: Why are you using SQL for this rather than the model layer?

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs here:

```
que = 'select * from tm_txn_age_severity_config where txn_state_id = %s and txn_type_id = %s and txn_age_severity_id in ( %s)'
in_ids = ', '.join(map(lambda x: '%s', critical_severity_list))
que = que % ('%s', in_ids)
```

You're formatting `que` using several arguments but you're not providing enough arguments. In `que` there are three occurrences of `%s` but you're only providing two arguments when you use the `%` operator to format the string.

For example:

```
>>> "%s %s" % "a"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

(one argument is provided, two are expected)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you want:

```
critical_severity_list=[30,40]
temp=['%s']+critical_severity_list
que = 'select * from tm_txn_age_severity_config where txn_state_id = %s and txn_type_id = %s and txn_age_severity_id in ( %s)'
que = que % tuple(i for i in temp)
print(que)
```

**output:**

```
select * from tm_txn_age_severity_config where txn_state_id = %s and txn_type_id = 30 and txn_age_severity_id in ( 40)
```